# Want to run Airflow in my IP address not in localhost

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Currently airflow is running on localhost but I want to run it on my IP address so that one can access my airflow with specific username and password. What changes should I make to configure of airflow to change the host from `0.0.0.0:8080` to my IP Address with same port number. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

need to change port number in config.file (web_server_port) & re-run airflow db init

Answer (score 0):

Try running airflow with the following command -

`airflow webserver --port 8080 --hostname 0.0.0.0`.
You should also make sure that firewall settings are set such that your machine is discoverable.
You should also allow incoming connections to port `8080`.
For eg, `ufw allow 8080`